# Getting events from Foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

Can I get **events** from Foursquare API or just **places**?

Answer (score 0):

You can get events via the API, documented at https://developer.foursquare.com/. In particular these two endpoints are probably what you're looking for:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/events
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/events/events

Note that there are limits on what sort of events you'll be able to retrieve as noted in the description for [/venues/events](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/events)